# ADAL java support for authentication via user credentials

Tags: azure, adal

AzureAD supports the OAuth Resource Owner Password Credential Grant.

The ADAL SDK has recently added support for it (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.8.10804.1442-rc)

Here the link for UserCredentials on ADAL .net library :
https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/ADAL.NET/UserCredential.cs

do we support Authentication via user credentials in the adal4j (adal java) library ??

Answer (score 1):

This is Brandon from the ADAL team. We do plan on adding support for  OAuth Resource Owner Password Credential Grant but it isn't there yet.

I've added this to our repo for tracking: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/issues/4

Comment: regarding the above mentioned github repo, the feature is completed by now.

Answer (score 0):

It is very very recent update to the ADAL library for .NET only. Note that this is not yet available even for the Windows Phone and Windows Store apps (which are also .NET).

And, from the [official GitHub Repository](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-java/tree/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/aad/adal4j), the most recent work on ADAL4J is from 4 months. So, no not yet available for Java clients.